# KOMA partformat with specific background and margins

Tags: margins, koma-script, backgrounds, parts

Currently I am writing a book which is structured using parts. I want the page with the parts to be formatted the following way:

- The roman part number in the background, which is currently obtained using `tikz` and `background`. Is there a better way to achieve this (maybe with KOMA internal macros, just asking because I use `\tikzexternalize`)?
- But the main point is the following: How can I use an `addmargin` environment around the title? I would like the title to span into the margin and there is no `\partlinesformat` or similar.
- *Added*: Is there a macro for applying another style to `\part*`?

[image: partformat]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,background,etoolbox}

\backgroundsetup{pages=some,angle=0,scale=50,color=blue!50,opacity=.1,contents={
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (current page.center) {\thepart};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}

\renewcommand*{\partformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\setkomafont{part}{\Huge\sffamily\BgThispage}

\begin{document}
    \part{This is a test with a very very long title}
        Here comes text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use package `scrlayer` or `scrlayer-scrpage` and define an own pagestyle for the part pages.

Here is an example assuming that all part pages are odd pages:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads xcolor and graphicx
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% loads scrlayer
\newcommand*\partnumber{}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  textarea,
  addwidth=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth,
  mode=picture,
  contents={%
    \putC{\makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\scalebox{50}{\textcolor{blue!5}{\partnumber}}}}}\gdef\partnumber{}%
  }
]{partnumber}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{part}{partnumber}
\renewcommand\partpagestyle{part}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\gdef\partnumber{\thepart}}

% only a dirty workaround for the part title
\newcommand*\changedpartwidth[1]{%
  \makebox[\linewidth][l]{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}{\raggedpart#1}%
  }%
}
% add \changedpartwidth as last command to the settings for font element part
\addtokomafont{part}{\Huge\changedpartwidth}

\begin{document}
\part{This is a test with a very very long title}
 Here comes text
\part{This is a test with a very very very very long title}
 Here comes text
\addpart{Part without Number}
\end{document}
```

The part number and title are centered horizontally to the textarea including the marginpar.

[image]
[image]
[image]